# Arbitrary Quadrilaterals

Tags: geometry

what is an arbitrary quadrilateral?

I can't find a definition of it anywhere. 
How would you find the area of an arbitrary quadrilateral?

Comment: A 'definition' is different than a 'formula'. As for formulas, there are some, including the one given in the answer. One other approach would be to consider two triangles and calculate their areas, or consider the formula $S=d_1 \cdot d_2\cdot \sin \theta /2$ where $d_i$ are the length of the diagonals and $\theta$ is the angle between them.

Comment: ok. thank you. do you know what am arbitrary quadrilateral exactly is?

Comment: @tylerw - it means any quadrilateral

Comment: It is as opposed to special quadrilaterals, like squares, rectangles, rhombuses, parallelograms, and trapezoids.  There may be more to be opposed to.

Comment: thank you. i understand it better now.

Answer (score 1):

Please see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bretschneider%27s_formula).

It is too complicated, I would rather to provide the link instead of copying it.

If you know all the coordinate of the quadrilateral, then use [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula).

Comment: ok, thanks. i will look at that link right away

Comment: It's a bit easy to copy formulae from Wikipedia. Right-click on the image, choose "properties", and in the alt-text, the $\LaTeX$ code is often shown. You can copy that and paste here for MathJax to parse.

Comment: @J.M. Many browsers (e.g. Safari and Chrome) do not have that feature. One can “Edit” the page on Wikipedia and copie the $\LaTeX$ from there (replacing `<math>…</math>` with `$…$`, though.